# GWT - Best way to set global css styles

Tags: css, gwt

We are using GXT with GWT which involves having one CSS file per base widget. What is the best way in GWT to have a global css style.

For example

```
global.css

.backgroundBorder {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-radius: 3px;
}
```

myWidget.css

```
@backgroundBorder
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. In addition I would include an interface in the above AppClientBundle.

```
public interface AppClientBundle extends ClientBundle {

  public static final AppClientBundle INSTANCE = GWT.create(AppClientBundle.class);

  @Source({ "css/template/global.css" })
  MyStyle css();
  public interface MyStyle extends CssResource {
    String backgroundBorder();
  }
}
```

This gives you the possibility to style your widget in this way:

```
Widget.setStylePrimaryName(AppClientBundle.INSTANCE.css().backgroundBorder());
```

Hope that helps ...

Comment: This seems like the best approach. I wasn't clear in the question that we are already using ClientBundle and CssResources.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ClientBundles and CssResources.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#CssResource

At your entrypoint you can set the global css.
Similar to that:

```
YourStyle.getTheme().getAppClientBundle().getGlobalCss().ensureInjected();
```

And you clientbundle could be similar like that:

```
public interface AppClientBundle extends ClientBundle {

    @Source({ "css/template/global.css" })
    CssResource getGlobalCss();

}
```

From my experiance, this is the best way.